# Unable to connect to Access database from Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access, pyodbc

i'm trying to connect to access database on my ubuntu 18 but i cant

```
self.con = pyodbc.connect(
r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};'
r'DBQ=C:\Users\Derar\PycharmProjects\ULMS\ulms.accdb;PWD=v7WC$=3ZJ5pX?h?TM54S')
self.cmd = self.con.cursor()
```

I Get This Error

```
''`r'DBQ=C:\Users\Derar\PycharmProjects\ULMS\ulms.accdb;PWD=v7WC$=3ZJ5pX?h?TM54S')
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`
```

Comment: Have you installed an Access ODBC driver for Linux? (Hint: Linux does not include an Access ODBC driver by default, and Microsoft does not provide Access ODBC drivers for non-Windows platforms.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with an Access database in Python on non-Windows platform (Linux or Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596737/working-with-an-access-database-in-python-on-non-windows-platform-linux-or-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your trying to run code written for Windows on Ubuntu.
It looks like the path name is not a POSIX style path.

You will need to configure linux odbc properly - or just install python on Windows and run your code there...

As far as I know there is no free linux ODBC driver for accdb files. You would likely have to convert the database, use commercial software, or access the DB from Windows.

Comment: This appears to be some commercial software which can provide Access file format support in linux... https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html#section=tab-1 

Instructions for configuring it are here: https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/getting-started.html

You'll obviously need to copy the access file or mount it over an SMB/CIFS share and modify your /etc/odbc.ini file accordingly

Answer (score -2):

See my answer here:

[Connect to MS Access in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757873/connect-to-ms-access-in-python/51457481#51457481)

I believe it's applicable to your scenario.

Comment: *"I believe it's applicable to your scenario."* - No, it isn't. Your linked(-only) answer and the blog post it cites are for a Windows environment. Microsoft does not produce an Access ODBC driver for non-Windows platforms. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596737/working-with-an-access-database-in-python-on-non-windows-platform-linux-or-mac) for details.